# CDO mail issue "The transport failed to connect to the server"

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to set up a userform in an Excel file that sends an email to report any bugs/issues the user finds with the spreadsheet.

```
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim Flds As Variant

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

iConf.Load -1
Set Flds = iConf.Fields

With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "bugreporter@gmail.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com" 'smtp mail server
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 'stmp server
    .Update
End With

With iMsg

    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "example@domain.com"
    .From = "bugreporter@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Hello"
    .TextBody = "Hi Dude"
    .Send
End With

Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
```

I get an error "The transport failed to connect to the server".  I don't know much about ports/port-forwarding, but I have tried ports 25, 465, and 587 and none of them work.  I am running this from a work network, but I assume at least one port must be open as we have Outlook running on everyone's computers.

I have enabled IMTP on the gmail account, as well as allowing less secure apps.

Comment: Try `smtpserverport") = 587 'stmp server`

Comment: Many corporate networks have rules setup to block usage of gmail.com via smtp. I would suggest trying your code outside of your work network.